# Access: DMax and String ID

Tags: ms-access

Because the developers of the Oracle database we use are hell-bent on making my life difficult :), they decided to use numbers for the PK for some tables and VARCHAR for the PK for other tables.

For the Access front-end I'm building, I have a form with a textbox which I want to display the last ID used on a table + 1 (so if the last ID was 100, then 101 would display in the box). Naturally, the table I need to do this on as a VARCHAR ID, even though all of the IDs are sequential numbers. Converting the field to numeric, while would fix my purpose, is not going to happen.

So, my question: in my other textbox where the ID is numeric, I am able to use DMAX to find the last number used; however, this isn't working for the string ID. I've read about using the Val() function to convert the string to text, but I can't figure out how to use both. I tried the following:

```
DMax(Val("[EAUSER_INFORMATION_ITEM]![INFORMATION_ITEM_ID]"),[EAUSER_INFORMATION_ITEM],"")
```

but this comes back with a #Name? error.

Would someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Comment: Even if you get this to work, the performance will be horrible, if the table is of any decent size. Do you actually need this value (because you have to set the PK for a new record yourself)? If no, I would just drop this textbox. If yes, I would escalate the issue to someone who can ... persuade ... the DB devs to not be idiots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Val` inside of the quotes, not outside of them, else you get this problem. Also, all arguments inside of a domain aggregates need to be strings:

```
DMax("Val([INFORMATION_ITEM_ID])","[EAUSER_INFORMATION_ITEM]")
```

You can omit the last argument, the `WHERE` condition, if you're not using it, and you don't need to specify the tablename if there's only one table.

You probably can't do anything about it, but using ascending numeric strings as primary keys is a major bad practice. Most database engines will sort in ascending order, causing massive fragmentation (because *"100" < "2"* is True)

Comment: Erik, thank you so much! This did work for me. I really appreciate all of your help. :)